# Is it legal to monitor police and weather channels without a license?

Tags: united-states, fcc

I have two HT's that I bought from Baofeng for emergency use and I don't have a license. I was wondering: is it perfectly legal in the USA for me to be monitoring police and weather channels without a license so long as I don't transmit on any frequency?

Comment: I'm inferring from the FCC tag that you mean to ask about US regulations

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "weather channels"? Do you mean NOAA broadcasts?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, That is perfectly legal, just as long as you **DO NOT transmit** on those frequency's. It will be just the same as if you were using any scanner, which you could not transmit with even if you wanted to.

Comment: Can you cite a reference?

Comment: Weather channels are a public broadcast and it is intended that anyone can listen. Some states have laws about monitoring police channels, esp., in furtherance of a crime. See for instance http://www.fireline.org/scanlaws/scanner5.html and a word about a federal exclusion of hams for these laws at http://www.fireline.org/scanlaws/federal4.html

Answer (score 3):

In some states it is not legal to have a scanner in your car.  See http://www.fireline.org/scanlaws/scanner5.html

In these states, it's *not* legal to have a ham radio in your car unless you have a ham license because police will consider it to be a scanner..

Apparently it's even a problem for hams that do have a license: http://www.eham.net/ehamforum/smf/index.php?topic=17576.0;wap2